# System.InvalidOperationException: No process is associated with this object, but Process is not null

Tags: c#, process, invalidoperationexception

hello Stack Overflow community.  I am trying to start a web browser with C#, it opens a new tab or window(depending on if a window is already open) but when I try to send a close window command with CloseMainWindow() it throws this exception.  I have read the documentation for InvalidOperationException and the answer is still not apparent.

here is my code

```
            Process defaultbrowser = new Process();
            defaultbrowser.StartInfo.FileName = target;
            defaultbrowser.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            defaultbrowser.Start();

           int waitTime = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value);
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(waitTime*1000);

           defaultbrowser.CloseMainWindow();
```

what I dont understand is that I have checked to see is defaultbrowser is null, and it is not.  Also I have initialized default browser and have started it.  I would expect that to mean that there is a process associated with defaultbrowser.

I do not understand, I would be grateful for any and all the help that I can get with this.

Comment: If an instance of the browser is already open, most browser processes will signal the other instance to open a tab or window and then die, so you’re left without a process. Run this, check `defaultbrowser.IsRunning` (is that the right name?), and then check for other instances of the browser. Or play with the Windows API to get the active window handle and close it; it depends on what you want to do, and neither approach is particularly nice.

Comment: You might also be able to [convince the browser to start a new instance](http://askubuntu.com/questions/35392/how-to-launch-a-new-instance-of-google-chrome-from-the-command-line), but again, it depends on the behaviour you want.